# Visual Studio 2015 Remote Azure Debug

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-mobile-services, remote-debugging

We have an ASP.NET Core API app on Azure. When we test our API on local machine it works fine. After publish on Azure strange things starts to happen, but there is no pattern, so we wanna debug our API on Azure to find the bug, but we can't figure out it how because we got error all the time. I am testing on Windows 10 x64, Visual Studio 205 update 3.

[image]

I tried to change in Build -> Configuration Manager az I read about it, but nothing, the same error.

I have installed the x64 version of Remote Debbuger. The 64bit version of debugger is running, I checked in the process tree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have installed the x64 version of Remote Debugger. The 64bit version of debugger is running, I checked in the process tree.

As far as I know, the remote tool is installed on the server-side automatically and the version of remote tool matches the version of operating system which is used to host your Azure App. I tested this issue on my side and got the information as follows:

[image]

After change the platform of my Azure App, I could remote debug the app on my side. Based on the error you provided, I assumed that the Platform architecture in your Azure app is set as 32-bit and the process you attached is x64. Please try to log in to the Azure Portal, choose your web app, click "SETTINGS > Application settings", change the Platform architecture to 64-bit and find whether it could work on your side.

Additionally, you could enable diagnostics logging for web apps in Azure App Service. For more details, you could refer to this [tutorial](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-enable-diagnostic-log/).

Comment: thnx, I will give a try and let you know

Comment: My application settings state that the Platform architecture for the Azure App is 64-bit yet I still get this error...

Comment: Turns out after installing the Remote Debugger you need to run "Remote Debugger Configuration Wizard". Oops!